# How do I manage conditional rendering in Flutter using Bloc without getting "boolean expression must not be null" error?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc, rxdart

I am just trying out flutter and I cannot seem to get components to render conditionally based on a BehaviourStream in my Bloc.

I wish to initially show the "_buildPage()" widget (which is an auth form), then while _isLoading is true but (_loginSucceded is false) I wish to show the spinner. Lastly, when _loginSucceded is true and _isLoading is false, I wish to redirect the user.

Actual behaviour is once form is submitted loader shows as expected. Once the response is successfully received from the server however the auth for is rendered once again.

I think my logic is fine but it seems that when I set the values of the stream in the Bloc constructor something else is causing the app to rerender which results in null values in the stream.

Is there a way to ensure a stream always has base values after the constructor has run upon initialisation?

Or is there a better way to manage this scenario? I have only just started looking at Flutter from a JS background so I may well be missing something.

Bloc code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import './auth_validator.dart';

class AuthBloc with AuthValidator {
  final _email = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _isLoading = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  final _loginSucceded = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

  AuthBloc() {
    _isLoading.sink.add(false);
    _loginSucceded.sink.add(false);
  }

  // stream getters
  Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Stream<String> get password => _password.stream.transform(validatePassword);
  Stream<bool> get isLoading => _isLoading.stream;
  Stream<bool> get loginSuccess => _loginSucceded.stream;
  Stream<bool> get submitValid =>
      Observable.combineLatest2(email, password, (e, p) => true);

  // add data to sink onChange
  Function(String) get emailChanged => _email.sink.add;
  Function(String) get passwordChanged => _password.sink.add;

  void submitForm() async {
    try {
      final Map user = {'email': _email.value, 'password': _password.value};
      final jsonUser = json.encode(user);

      _isLoading.sink.add(true);

      // submit to server
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        'http://192.168.1.213:5000/api/users/signin',
        body: jsonUser,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      );

      final Map<String, dynamic> decodedRes = await json.decode(response.body);

        _isLoading.sink.add(false);
        _loginSucceded.sink.add(true);

      void dispose() {
        _email.close();
        _password.close();
        _isLoading.close();
        _loginSucceded.close();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
      _isLoading.sink.add(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Widget code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../blocs/auth_bloc.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final authBloc = AuthBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.loginSuccess,
      builder: (context, snapshot1) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: authBloc.isLoading,
          builder: (context, snapshot2) {
            print('loginSuccess? ${snapshot1.data} isLoading? ${snapshot2.data}');
            return Scaffold(
                body: !snapshot1.data && snapshot2.data
                    ? _circularSpinner()
                    : snapshot1.data && snapshot2.data
                        ? Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard')
                        : _buildPage());
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _emailField(authBloc),
              _padding(),
              _passwordField(authBloc),
              _padding(),
              _submitButton(authBloc)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _circularSpinner() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget _emailField(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.email,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.emailChanged,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'you@example.com',
            labelText: 'Email Address',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordField(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.password,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.passwordChanged,
          obscureText: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: '8 characters or more with at least 1 number',
            labelText: 'Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _padding() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    );
  }

  Widget _submitButton(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.submitValid,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Login'),
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: snapshot.hasError ? null : authBloc.submitForm,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './app.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './pages/auth.dart';
import './pages/dashboard.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
        '/dashboard': (BuildContext context) => DashBoardPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Log

```
Restarted application in 1,462ms.
I/flutter ( 4998): loginSuccess? false isLoading? false
I/flutter ( 4998): loginSuccess? null isLoading? null
I/flutter ( 4998): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4998): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<bool>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 4998): _StreamBuilderBaseState<bool, AsyncSnapshot<bool>>#34870):
I/flutter ( 4998): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
I/flutter ( 4998):
I/flutter ( 4998): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 4998): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 4998): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 4998):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 4998):
I/flutter ( 4998): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4998): #0      LoginPage.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
```

Comment: add initialValue: to the StreamBuilders

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I do that? The only thing I could find in the docs with regard to initialValue was on the fold method

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SvRP1XS

Comment: Ah, sorry and thanks! I was looking at the BehaviourSubject! That cleared the errors. Still strange behaviour though. On the StreamBuilder the authBloc.loginSuccess is still printing as false, even though when I manually add a listener in the bloc file it correctly shows true.

Comment: Seems like it didn't like nested StreamBuilders. As a result I added a getter using combineLatest2 in rxdart. I now just query that

Answer (score 0):

as user @user10539074 mentioned, you need to set initial data for the first run of the streambuilder - ie. in your code - if authBloc.isLoading is bool, than change:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: authBloc.isLoading,
          builder: (context, snapshot2) {
```

to:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: authBloc.isLoading,
          initialData: true,
          builder: (context, snapshot2) {
```